# jbutton.setEnabled(false) doesn't disable button input

Tags: java, swing

I have the following two classes:

**#1**

```
public class LobbyView extends JPanel
{       

    private final JButton sendGameRequestButton = new JButton();

    public JButton getSendGameRequestButton()
    {
        return sendGameRequestButton;
    }

    LobbyView()
    {
        sendGameRequestButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(15, 20));
        sendGameRequestButton.setText("Send game request");
        sendGameRequestButton.addMouseListener(new LobbyListener(this));
        sendGameRequestButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

**#2**

```
public class LobbyListener implements MouseListener
{
    LobbyView lobbyView;

public LobbyListener(LobbyView sentLobbyView)
{
    lobbyView = sentLobbyView;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (e.getButton() == 1)
    {      
        if (e.getSource() == lobbyView.getSendGameRequestButton())
        {
            System.out.println("You pushed the disabled button");
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I disabled the JButton in the LobbyView constructor, I can still click it and get the message "*You pushed the disabled button*".

Does **component.setEnabled(false)** actually DISABLE a component, or just gray it out to make it LOOK disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Even though I disabled the JButton in the LobbyView constructor, I can still click it

That is correct. You should NOT be using a MouseListner. The MouseListener works independent of the state of the button.

Instead you should be using an `ActionListener`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information. Or there is also a section on `How to Write an Action Listener`.